# $state.go() is not passing params to url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, states

I was using `ui-sref` for this. It worked fine but I can't use it in this situation because I'm using a `ng-repeat` and I don't want it to be executed on every item. So I decided to make a function, which contains a simply `$state.go()` with a param.

defining:

```
.config(
        ["$stateProvider", // more dependencies
            ($stateProvider: angular.ui.IStateProvider) => {
                $stateProvider
                    .state("app.projectstart.project", {
                        url: "project/:parentId",
                        templateUrl: "gui/projectstart/project/project.html",
                        controller: "ProjectstartProjectController"
                    });
            }
        ]);
```

calling:

```
this.modelFactory.$state.go("app.projectstart.project", {parentId: item.parentId});
```

I want the url to be like

`"http://localhost:9000/#/app/projectstart/project/10000?functionId=clockin"`

But the only thing I get is

```
"http://localhost:9000/#/app/projectstart/project/?functionId=clockin"
```

Why is it not passing the parentId to the url? I defined it in `.config`.

Thanks in advance.
greetings johnny

Edit:

I'm sure that 'item.parentId' has a Value. It's either '10000' or '20000'. I assigned parentId with '10000', It's still the same.

Comment: Did you debug what's inside "item" object before the $state.go ?? Maybe it's empty... check in console what is the value of it and tell

Comment: I back @raulchopi, it looks like racing issue since there is nothing wrong with the code itself

Comment: I'm sure that 'item.parentId' is either 10000, 20000 or 30000.
i did put "10000" as integer into the variable "parentId". It's still the same